# How to implement protostream with AutoProtoSchemaBuilder for Data Grid Red Hat remote cache

Tags: java, maven, infinispan, hot-rod, redhat-datagrid

I have a java application managed from maven.
I have implemented Data Grid cache with `org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCacheManager` version 8.2 to connect the application to distribuited remote cache service.

Followed the link page Red Hat https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/8.2/html/cache_encoding_and_marshalling/marshalling_user_types
to implement protostream object. Let me show how I have implemented the app, because I'm not able to generate automatically via `@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder`the concrete classes as described from the guide:

[image]

Example implemented:

**pom.xml** file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
  <artifactId>infinispan-bom</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.7.Final-redhat-00001</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
  <artifactId>infinispan-client-hotrod</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-jcache-remote -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-jcache-remote</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan.protostream</groupId>
    <artifactId>protostream-processor</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**LibraryInitalizer.java** Interface

```
package com.xxx.wa.configurator.cache.protostream;

import org.infinispan.protostream.GeneratedSchema;
import org.infinispan.protostream.annotations.AutoProtoSchemaBuilder;

import com.ducati.wa.configurator.cache.protostream.test.Home;

@AutoProtoSchemaBuilder(includeClasses = { Home.class }, schemaFileName = "simple.proto", schemaFilePath = "proto/", schemaPackageName = "com.ducati.wa.configurator.cache.protostream.test")
public interface LibraryInitalizer extends GeneratedSchema{

}
```

**Home.java** as object for testing

```
package com.xxx.wa.configurator.cache.protostream.test;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.infinispan.protostream.annotations.ProtoFactory;
import org.infinispan.protostream.annotations.ProtoField;


public class Home implements Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ProtoField(number = 1)
    String name;
    
    @ProtoField(number = 2)
    String address;
    
    
    public Home() {
        super();
    }
    @ProtoFactory
    public Home(String name, String address) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    
    
}
```

The issue faced is the missed LibraryInitalizerImpl class autogenerate, I once done `mvn clean compile` maven command.

Currently I'm using `org.apache.maven.plugins`, Do you know the autogenerate issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Just to update my post.

I found out the issue.
In Maven plugin was disabled the annotation processors.

I added the  tag for *protostream-processor* as followed:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <annotationProcessorPath>
       <groupId>org.infinispan.protostream</groupId>
        <artifactId>protostream-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
    </annotationProcessorPath>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

the  `<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>` did not allow the annotation processor. the finally`maven-compiler-plugin`works fine is the followed :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <!--  <configuration>
        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
    </configuration> -->
    <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <annotationProcessorPath>
           <groupId>org.infinispan.protostream</groupId>
            <artifactId>protostream-processor</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
        </annotationProcessorPath>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```